# Make a notebook tab anchored so its position cannot be changed

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a GtkNotebook that will contain at the very least, one permanent tab, called "Search".  The widget within this page allows for more pages to be created, and these pages have a tab that contains a close button.

How do I make the tabs reorderable, but also keep the "Search" tab anchored at position 0? The current behavior of gtk.Notebook.set_tab_reorderable() is that it allows you to physically drag a tab to reorder it...it doesn't stop that tab from being forced to reorder itself when a reorderable tab moves past it.

Example:

This first image is the default positions:

[image]

This image is the result of dragging Row#6( where Row#6 is reorderable but Search isn't):
[image]

How do I keep "Search" from being reordered by 'reorderable' tabs?

Comment: Always a good idea to show the offending code parts!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to me like a possible solution would be to connect to the `'page-reordered'` signal like this:

```
import gtk

 def on_reorder(notebook, child, number, user_data):
     if number == 0:
         notebook.reorder_child(user_data, 0)

 def main():
     mainwin = gtk.Window()
     notebook = gtk.Notebook()
     mainwin.add(notebook)
     mainwin.set_default_size(200,200)
     for label in ['Search', 'Row#6', 'Row#9']:
         child = gtk.VBox()
         notebook.append_page(child, gtk.Label(label))
         if label != 'Search':
             notebook.set_tab_reorderable(child, True)
         else:
             notebook.set_tab_reorderable(child, False)
     searchtab = notebook.get_nth_page(0)
     notebook.connect('page-reordered', on_reorder, searchtab)

     mainwin.show_all()
     mainwin.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
     gtk.main()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That will do the trick. It seems there is no way to tell the notebook that you can't anchor a certain position so no tabs will move it around. But this is close enough behavior.